# Save user variables in sharedpreference and connect class with MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have to hit a service and if the response came true than I have to verify the user & save the user entered variables in shared preference. my url is: http://a.nextput.com/apps/init/4/a/9fe2d2cbaa8332a4633be17b79208181-2y-10-ELVM4HwkaYaCVu6203Zjfus-G/o?aff_id and the response it is giving is {"success":true}. For this I have made a class and declared a static method. Inside the static method I have to do parsing. 
my class:

```
public class InitializeSDK {
/*String json = "";
URL url;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;*/
public static void init(final Context ctx, int offerwall_id, String offerwall_public_key) {

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        //TODO: add code to read http request and store the json data in json variable
        String json = "";
        //URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://a.nextput.com/apps/init/4/a/9fe2d2cbaa8332a4633be17b79208181-2y-10-ELVM4HwkaYaCVu6203Zjfus-G/o?aff_id");//YOUR URL

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            boolean isSuccess = jObj.getBoolean("success");
            System.out.println("success : " + isSuccess);


            // SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    /*SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context ctx);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isSuccess",isSuccess);
    editor.commit();*/
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

      /* JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
boolean state = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");*/

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


    }

}.execute();
}
```

my MainActivity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

}
}
```

How to save the variables in sharedpreference and connect the class with MainActivity? Please help

Comment: What do you mean with "connect the class with MainActivity"?

Comment: I guess he doesn't know how to 'use' his  InitializeSDK class in his Activity

Comment: Can you please help?

Comment: you don't have any value to parse except success message update your api first

Answer (score 0):

Do the below changes.
Step1: Change Return type Void to Boolean

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {}
```

Step2: In doInBackground return "isSuccess"

Step3: Change the onPostExecute() below

```
protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result){
          PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .edit()
            .putInt"offerwall_id", offerwall_id)
            .putString("offerwall_public_key",offerwall_public_key)
            .apply();
   }

}
```

Step4: Call from MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final Context context = this;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
InitializeSDK.init(this,val1,val2);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: in the mainactivity what should I pass in val1 and val2. Please help

Comment: val1,val2 are the value which your pass it asynctask and save in preference.

Comment: Do I need to paste the whole SharedPreference code into onPostExecute() ??

Comment: in the postexecute method in if(result) line it is giving error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference. Can you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make InitializeSDK class extend AsyncTask

like

```
public class InitializeSDK extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
       Context ctx;
       int offerwall_id;
       String offerwall_public_key;

       public InitializeSDK (Context ctx, int offerwall_id, String offerwall_public_key){
          this.ctx = ctx;
          this.offerwall_id = offerwall_id;
          this.offerwall_public_key = offerwall_public_key;

       }
      //rest of the asynctask code
}
```

and in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int id = //your id;
    String offerwall_public_key = //your key;
    new IntializeSDK(this,id,offerwall_public_key).execute();
 }
```

Your shared preference code is correct, use it in OnPostExecute

Comment: What parameters I should pass in MainActivity? Please help

Comment: The context, offerwall_id and offerwall_public_key

Comment: it says cannot resolve symbol 'offerwall_id' and 'offerwall_public_key'.

Comment: Those are the parameters you specified in your init function. If you are not going to use them (your code doesn't seem to make use of them), then remove it from the constructor and only pass the context from MainActivity

Comment: Actually I need them. It is just a part of my full project. Can you please code how to initialize them in the MainActivity? Please

Comment: Ive edited the code. You have to initialize id and the key with values ( how you get those depend on you)